# Match column values and ignoring the special characters in the strings in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
name                                                id                          name_matched                                      
0.5% timolol fixed combination ophthalmic solution  3275172                     brimonidine
drop)                                               3275173                     brimonidine tartrate
0.2% w                                              3275174                     chlorhexidine digluconate
0.2μg act-hib®                                      3275175                     act hib
1.0% prednisolone acetate association               3275176                     gatifloxacin
0.3% topical minocycline ointment                   3275177                     minocycline.
```

I would like to keep only those rows where name = name_matched

When I tried below query, I was missing row4 and row6 due to special characters in the name value. How can I ignore those characters and get those rows in my output.

```
select *
FROM tbl
where name not ilike '%' || name_matched || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you are trying to articulate here is that the `name_matched` needs to be a substring of the `name` to make a match:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE name ILIKE '%' || name_matched || '%';
```

If the above might be giving a few false positives (or negatives), then we could consider using regex here, but maybe you don't need to do that.

Comment: 0.2μg act-hib® and act hib AND 0.3% topical minocycline ointment                      minocycline. are not matched